# Error with pathing and serving static files from folder within views directory

Tags: node.js, express, static

I usually put my files in the public directory and use the following to serve them:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

However for this project I am using a template that has all its images and data stored in the assets folder, so I used the following:

```
app.use("/assets",  express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));
```

This is my directory structure:
[image]

and as long as I was rendering views that are in the main views folder everything was working ok. But then for products I created a products folder and I was storing my views there e.g. the TI-401M.ejs is a product ejs view that I was storing in a products folder, but all the links are broken. However if I place the TI-401M.ejs file in the main views directory everything works, but obviously I dont want my product views being stored in the main views dir.
I also tried amongst other things to do:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));
```

which is supposed to serve all static files inside the assets folder no matter what. But this also doesnt work.

I think the problem is coming from my paths and I am making some mistake within the pathing. I read the docs on express.static and saw some videos but cant figure it out.

(I also think I saw that it seems when I place the view in the products folder its searching under products/assets and not directly in /assets)

Can someone explain to me please what I am doing wrong and how the pathing for express.static and its correlation to my directory structure (why it works in the main views dir but not in the products dir inside the views dir?)

Thank You